# How to get records if value is null with two meanings in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table named as "**Process**". It has the following columns:

- process_id
- process_type
- status
- created_date
- updated_date
- created_by

**Status** can be 1,2,3 and null.

- status 1 = Approved Process
- status 2 = Disapproved Process
- status 3 = Canceled Process
- status null = In-Progress

Now i have a page with a grid, a drop down and a button. Drop down contains the option of "Approved(1), disapproved(2),Canceled(3)". What i am doing is i am fetching all records if there is no selection in drop down. I get the value of drop down and it is null if there is no selection in drop down. In SQL query, i implemented that if **@status** parameter is null then fetch all records and if **@status** parameter gets the value (1,2,3) then i filter it. Below is the query:

```
@status as int = null
Select * 
From Process
where @status IS NULL 
Or  Process.status = @status
```

Till here, Everything is working fine for me. Now the interesting thing is i need to add a new option in drop down **In-Progress**. In process table, 
In-progress Process are with null value. I already making decision if @status is null to fetch all records. How i manage if there is no selection in drop down to get all records and if In-Progress is selected then fetch only records with status null? Please suggest.

Comment: You can assign a value to in-progress in your drop down list (ie 0= In-progress) and filter the same in query (.. where astatus IS NULL OR ISNULL(Process.status,0) = @status ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

```
IF @status = 'INPROGRESS' 
    Select * 
    From Process
    where Process.status IS NULL
ELSE IF @status <> ''
    Select * 
    From Process
    where Process.status = @status
ELSE
    Select * 
    From Process
```

Comment: Yes, i already think about this. Thanks. Waiting for more suggestions.

Comment: I did with this logic. Assign a value to In-pro and then check in sp like you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
Select p.* 
From Process p
where coalesce(p.status, 'In Progress') = @status;
```

I should note that your query is incorrect, because `= NULL` *never* returns true.  I assume you want your original query to be:

```
Select * 
From Process
where @status is null or
      Process.status = @status
```

Comment: Yes it IS NULL. I just wrote mistakenly is question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a new label for the in progress status, and not attempt to rely on `NULL` for this purpose.  You can implement this at the database level by having a default value for the `status` column:

```
ALTER TABLE Process ALTER COLUMN status SET DEFAULT 4
```

Now if you see the value `4` for status, you will know that the user has not yet selected a value and he should choose.

By the way, as @Gordon already pointed out, you can't compare `NULL` values in SQL Server (or MySQL) using equals, but rather you must use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM Process
WHERE status IS NULL -- or IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can assign a value to the new drop down item 'In-Progress', eg 0=In progress. So u will get the value @status = 0 , when the In-progress is selected from drop down list. Then you can try the below query

```
Select * 
From Process
where @status IS NULL 
Or  ISNULL(Process.status,0) = @status --(here @status is 0 or 1 or 2 or 3)
```